# Capistrano - Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Capistrano didn't work correctly. So can't deploy my app.
Here's the error.

```
$ bundle exec cap staging deploy
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ec2-user@13.112.91.105
```

Here's config file, named config/deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'dola'
set :repo_url, 'git@ghe.intelligence-dev.com/inolab/eiicon-dola.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }.call
set :branch, 'master'

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/dola'

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.2-p217'
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
set :rbenv_roles, :all
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/backup tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle}
role :web, %w{13.112.91.105}

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

And here's config/deploy/staging.rb

```
 Simple Role Syntax
# ==================
# Supports bulk-adding hosts to roles, the primary server in each group
# is considered to be the first unless any hosts have the primary
# property set.  Don't declare `role :all`, it's a meta role.

role :app, %w{ec2-user@13.112.91.105}
role :web, %w{ec2-user@13.112.91.105}

# Extended Server Syntax
# ======================
# This can be used to drop a more detailed server definition into the
# server list. The second argument is a, or duck-types, Hash and is
# used to set extended properties on the server.
server '13.112.91.105', user: 'ec2-user', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value

# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
set :stage, :staging
set :rails_env, 'staging'
server '13.112.91.105', user: 'ec2-user',
roles: %w{web app} 
set :ssh_options, {
   keys: [File.expand_path('~/.ssh/id_rsa_ec2.pem)')]
}
```

Anyone, please!

Comment: are your deployment keys and ssh keys configured properly?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. BTW, what do you mean by 'deployment key'?

Answer (score 2):

Capistrano is trying to establish an SSH session between your computer and the machine to which you are trying to deploy your application - 13.112.91.105 in this case. In order to do that, given your Capistrano configuration, you need to be able to authenticate to the SSH server that is running on 13.112.91.105 as the user `ec2-user` using your SSH private key, which I'm assuming is `~/.ssh/id_rsa_ec2.pem`. For this to happen, your corresponding SSH **public** key must be listed in the `authorized_keys` file for `ec2-user` on the machine 13.112.91.105.

Comment: I see. I'd try to configure as you advised me later. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. After coming to work, I did as you described. It works!
Thank you.

Comment: @edurante if it's the correct answer, you can accept it.

Comment: This didn't work for me. ssh'ing with the key works, but capistrano tasks do not run, saying  Authentication failed.